# iOS Local Notifications with an API call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to create a local notification with the following requirements:

- The user sets the days of the week for the notification
- The user selects the time of day for the notification
- **The message of the notification requires calling an API to get the content.**

*For example, the user wants to know what the traffic is like on their commute every weekday at 0800.*

There are some great tutorials on creating Local Notifications (like this one [Adding Local Notifications in Your iOS App - appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)), but I would like to know if I can make an API call to populate the message of the notification.

So rather than having an annoying "*Check out the traffic now*" notification which can quickly direct the user to the relevant page in my app, I would like to have: "*There is minor congestion on the {road}*" or "*The roads look clear right now*"

Is this at all possible? Thanks.

---

**EDIT: Post iOS7 release**

So it seems we have;

- Background Fetch - able to fetch the new content and keep the content up-to-date
- Remote Notifications - able to download the content when the app receives the push notification

Neither of these work in my scenario. I need to make a call as close to the user's specified time as possible. With background fetch, it is no use if the last update was at 5am when the roads were probably clear. Remote notifications are not ideal either as I am not pushing a notification, I would be displaying a local notification.

Does anyone know of a clever workaround to achieve this solution?

Comment: How does your app know the weather in New York when offline (reliant on local notifications)?

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's what I am trying to figure out how to do, it would need to make an API call to get that data. But I do not think it is possible and so push notifications may be the only option.

Comment: This is not possible in iOS 6. You should explore whats new in iOS 7; you may find that things have changed. (Remember that iOS 7 is still under NDA, so any discussion needs to go to the dev forums.)

Comment: @RobNapier This fills me with high anticipation and excitement. Perhaps, just maybe, you will be answering this question sometime in September.

Comment: I think this can be achievable if the app is in background all the time and is never quit. A timer can be triggered from the date selected and there can be an api call at that moment, get the data set a local notification... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632996/schedule-multiple-daily-events-with-nstimer