# If statement: 2 different functions equaling each other - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm making an alarm clock, and when the time in the `UIDatePicker` is equal to the exact time I want a function to execute so I tried this:

```
if theDatePicker == strDate {
    playTheSound()
} else {
    println("HELLO")
}
```

**Function I want to execute when the `UIDatePicker` is equal to the exact time**

```
func playTheSound() {
    var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Annoying_Alarm_Clock-UncleKornicob-420925725", ofType: "mp3")!)
    playSound.text = "\(alertSound)"

    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WAKE UP", message:nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    alert.message = "ITS TIME TO WAKE UP"

    let dismissHandler = {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        })
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I'm Up!", style: .Default, handler: dismissHandler))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    }
}
```

**Getting the exact time**

```
func getTime() {
    var date = NSDate()
    var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
    outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    timeLabel.text = (outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))  // This line here will update your timeLabel with the current time every second
}
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("getTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

**My UIDatePicker is called theDatePicker**

```
func handler(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strDate = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(theDatePicker.date)
}
```

**My Question**
When the UIDatePicker and the exact time are equal I want playTheSound() to run.

Thank you for the time and patience.

Cheers!

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: When the UIDatePicker and the exact time are equal I want playTheSound() to run. @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: Updated question please remove `unclear what you are asking` if you find fitting

Comment: When you ran the code at the top, are you claiming that the two values are equal but `playTheSound` isn't being called, or is being called but isn't doing the right thing?  Or is the code at the top not being called?

Comment: I want it to execute **when** they are equal like an alarm @ScottHunter

Comment: Your code to compare the current system time with the time set in the picker must be in your `getTime()` method.

Comment: "When the UIDatePicker and the exact time are equal I want playTheSound() to run" is not a question. It's a desire. You don't say in what way the code you showed fails to satisfy that desire or in what way you're confused about how to satisfy your desire.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a timed event or if you also want the call to be made when the app is not active, then you could use local notifications. After selecting a date in the datepicker schedule one of these.

Both are explained in this stack overflow post: [Schedule multiple, daily events with NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632996/schedule-multiple-daily-events-with-nstimer)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend a Local Notification; this way, you'll be able to act even if your app is not open.

Essentially, you call to the system to schedule at a specific time (you can pull this from your date picker). When the schedule event occurs - whether your app is open or closed - the system calls back to your app though a delegate method. You can then act on the event (i.e. play your sound).